# Rota angular direcionar para pasta com Wordpress

Tags: angular

Minha aplicação Angular está na raiz do domínio e quero que ao digitar uma rota vazia ele redirecione para `/home`, onde nesta pasta tenho o WordPress instalado. Ou seja sempre que digitar apenas www.dominio.com a rota leve para `/home` onde esta instalado o WordPress.

**meu arquivo de rotas**

```
export const ROUTES:Routes = [
 {
    path: 'home', component:PublicComponent,
    children: [            
      { path: },          
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'clientnotfound',component:PublicComponent, 
    children: [            
      { path: '',component: PastaClienteComponent},

    ] 
  },       
  {
    path: 'confirmado',component:PublicComponent, 
    children: [            
      { path: ':id',component: CadastroFinalComponent},

    ] 
  },    


  // Main redirect
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},  

  // Handle all other routes
  {path: '**',  redirectTo: '/clientnotfound'}
];
```

**imagem do diretório final**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas o **{{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }}** não funcionou?

Comment: quando o usuário digita www.dominio.com ele leva para componente home (que não contem o wordpress), ja quando de digita www.dominio.com/home ele carrega o wordpress que esta nesta pasta, ignorando a rota.

Comment: Poderia inserir uma imagem de como estão dispostos as pastas no projeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você tem uma rota mapeada para `/home` quando você aplica o redirect essa rota é chamada dentro do contexto do Angular.

Você pode criar um componente e utilizar `window.localion.href=` para voltar para seu DNS raíz. Exemplo:

```
export class ReComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        window.location.href = 'www.dominio.com';
    }
}

// no arquivo de rotas:
{path: '', component: ReComponent }
```

Não ficou muito elegante mas resolve o problema. Como alternativa encontrei este [artigo](https://medium.com/@adrianfaciu/using-the-angular-router-to-navigate-to-external-links-15cc585b7b88) que mostra algo parecido utilizando um resolver.